# Textmate + Ruby: ruby: warning: -K is specified; it is for 1.8 compatibility and may cause odd behavior

Tags: ruby, textmate

I'm using textmate and when I try to use a shortcut to duplicate a line (ctrl + shift + d) it is giving me an error `ruby: warning: -K is specified; it is for 1.8 compatibility and may cause odd behavior`.

This is weird because it just started doing this a few days ago. I pointed my textmate to point to 1.8 as another stackoverflow answer suggested, and that worked for a few months but all of a sudden it's not working anymore. How would I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[TextMate 1.x under Mavericks](http://blog.macromates.com/2013/textmate-1-x-under-mavericks/):

> If you wish to use TextMate 1.x on Mavericks you will need to tell TextMate to use ruby 1.8 for bundle items by putting the path to it first via the `PATH` variable.
>
> Open Preferences from the TextMate menu and go to the Advanced section and select the *Shell Variables* tab. Click the + button to add a new variable named `PATH` with a value of:
>
> ```
>     /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
> ```

Comment: Looks like version 1.8 was removed from Yosemite.  I use RVM, and fixed it by installing 1.8 and pointing it to /Users/<USERNAME>/.rvm/rubies/<RUBY1.8>/bin.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this issue. I think it began after I upgraded to Yosemite. I found a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4302785/textmate-toggle-comment-macro-is-broken) that suggested reinstalling Textmate. When I went to download the app Textmate's website recommended upgrading to TextMate 2.0 if you are using OS X 10.9 or later. I upgraded and have no more Ruby warnings.

> For OS X 10.9 and later, TextMate 1.x is not suitable as it relies on
>   system >components no longer available.

https://macromates.com/download